# Am I being scammed again?

Tags: wallet, fraud, trust, cash-app

I recently was scammed out of $1000.00 a person recommended this Instagram site that assists in recovering stolen money. I was asked to pay a fee to obtain a program needed to move the money I foolishly paid the $85 and then was sent to another person that handles the end of it. He had me signup for Cashapp and then Trust wallet to move the scammed money back to me. I did not link any accounts of my own personal banking or cards. But he then said there was an mistake that he made and showed me a BNB Smart Chain Watch only wallet that showed a large sum of money and he wants it back. Using Cashapp. I am so naive about this and I don't want my money back or his but if it is true would assist in sending his back. Am I being scammed again? Please help I don't know what to do.

Comment: Yes, you’re being scammed again.

Comment: Yes, this is a scam. If somebody had a magical program that could recover your money, they wouldn't sell it to you - they'd use it to steal the money for themselves. Further, if such a program were possible at all, cryptocurrency would be fundamentally broken. I'm sorry for your loss, but the only option is to report the theft to authorities, or move on.